# solr indexing - connection timeout

Tags: java, mongodb, solr

I am loading data in **Solr** from **MongoDB**.

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

BasicDBObject record = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
doc.addField("_id", record.get("_id"));
// add more fields
server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

I am getting below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:64)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

This code worked for me before. I did not change anything in the code. But now its giving error after adding few documents. What's wrong here?

Comment: Well you are talking to two middlewares: Is the Solr server up and running? On the usual Port it always has? Username and Password correct? The same holds true for the MongoDB.

Comment: Yes solr is up and running.  Username and Password is also correct